# Cannot obtain a limit though the answer can be seen from series expansion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I am considering the order of magnitude of $l_a(s)$ when $s\to\infty$:

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = a > 0;
Out[1]= l = 1/2 a (-2 Cos[a s] CosIntegral[a s] + Sin[a s] (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[a s]));
In[2]:= Limit[l, s -> \[Infinity]]
Out[2]= 0
In[3]:= Series[l, {s, \[Infinity], 8}] // FullSimplify
Out[3]= (* textual output too clumsy; see the snapshot *)
```

[image]

which seems to be saying that $l_a(s)\sim\dfrac{1}{as^2}$ when $s\to\infty$ if $a>0$. However,

```
In[4]:= Limit[a s^2 l, s -> \[Infinity]]
Out[4]= Limit[1/2 a^2 s^2 (-2 Cos[a s] CosIntegral[a s] 
            + Sin[a s] (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[a s])), s -> \[Infinity]]
In[5]:= Limit[a s^2 Series[l, {s, +\[Infinity], 8}], s -> \[Infinity]]
Out[5]= 1
```

I tried a couple of other expansion order, and all give 1. Why is the limit in `In[4]` cannot be calculated by Mathematica directly?

Version: 11.2.0.0;
Platform: Windows (64-bit)

Comment: What version are you using?  MMa 11.0.1 returns 1 for `In[4]`.

Comment: @BillWatts 11.2.0.0 on Windows

Comment: `Series` often provides results that `Limit` cannot.

Comment: you can define a new function `f[z_]:=1/2 (-2 Cos[z] CosIntegral[z] + Sin[z] (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[z]))`. You'll see that $l(a,s)=a f(as)$ and MMa deals well with `f`.

Comment: @yohbs what is your version?

Comment: @ziyuang 11.0.1